# Query string on main page causes 404

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, http-status-code-404, query-string

In the website we developed,

```
 www.website.com/design?somequerystring
```

works fine but

```
 www.website.com?somequerystring
```

causes 404 error. We have already checked and are sure that there is no problem with the codes and it must be something about IIS. Also there is no url re-write. What do you think the error could be? What should we check?

Comment: Are you using MVC framework?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to add. MVC 5

Comment: Then it will be a problem with your routes, can you add the routes in your question?